# Datatables Jquery Bootstrap 5 Create dynamic dropdown in row and post data to php file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, datatables

I am using Datatables and I am trying to fetch user details from the database using Php/Sql and create a bootstrap 5 dropdown to show the employees as options. So far so good, the dropdown is showing the employees. The user than selects a employee to give the task to and I do this with jquery to post it to a php file.

My problem, the employee id from the fetched dropdown as `value` from my php file is stored in the variable `EmployeeId` and the client ID which is comming from the Datatables data is stored in the name atribute and named as `ClientId`. They are all present in the html. No I wish to post both to my update php, but only the `EmployeeId` is posted to my server.

My Question. Based on below codes (I am new to coding and I have no idea how to reproduce what i need in a snipchat or something, so sorry guys). How do I post the `ClientId` from the datatable row name atribute together with my name atribute from the fetched dropdown in php?

The php to fetch dropdown results:

```
$stmt8 = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT naam,id FROM gebruikers WHERE group_name = ? GROUP BY naam");
$stmt8->bind_param("s",$groupname);
$stmt8->execute();
$result = $stmt8->get_result(); 


// Build the options
while ($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
    
    $options .= '<li><button value= "' . $row["id"] . '" aria-label="ChangeEmployee" class="dropdown-item ChangeEmployee" type="button"><i class="fas fa-user-tie styleicon"></i>' . $row["naam"] . '</button></li>';
}


echo $options;
```

The script and the part of datatables to present the options:

```
  $.ajax({  // New ajax
    url: './PlanningSelectUserRealtime.php',
    method: 'GET',
    dataType: 'text',
    success:function(data)
    {
      ChangeEmployee = data;
    
    },
    error:function(xhr, status, err)
    {
      console.log('PlanningSelectUserRealtime.php error ' + err);
    }
  });
```

//datatable part

```
{data: 'resposible_client',
            render: function ( data, type, row, meta ) {
            return ' <div class="intplan_menudropdown dropdown" ><span>'+data+' </span><span aria-label="ChangeEmployeeResponsible" id="dropdownMenu' + row.client_id + '" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false" class="badge bg-secondary" name="' + row.client_id + '"><i class="fas fa-exchange-alt"></i></span><ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu' + row.client_id + '" >' + ChangeEmployee + '</ul></div>';
            } } ,
```

The script to post the details to my update php and where I need those both variables.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
     var table = $('#planningTable').DataTable();
     
     $("#planningTable").on("click", ".ChangeEmployee", function () {
        
     var EmployeeId = $(this).val();
var ClientId = $(this).attr('name');
 bootbox.confirm({
    title: "Administratie Bijgewerkt?",
    message: "Weet je zeker dat deze medewerker deze administratie gaat bijwerken?",
    buttons: {
        cancel: {
            label: '<i class="fa fa-times"></i> Nee, niet aanpassen'
        },
        confirm: {
            label: '<i class="fa fa-check"></i> Ja, aanpassen'
        }
    },
    callback: function (result) {
    
        var p = loadPrompt();
        if(result === false){
  
        p.inform('Medewerker is niet aangepast'); 
        }
        else{ 
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "RealtimeUpdateEmployee.php",
        data: {ClientId: ClientId,EmployeeId,EmployeeId},
        success: function(data) {
        $.ajax({  
                     url:"../oomkb_menu/oomkb_index_menu.php",  
                     method:"POST",  
                    data: {refreshdata: refreshdata}, 
                     dataType : 'json', 
                    
                     success:function(data){  
                      if (data.code == "200"){
    $('#planningTable').DataTable().ajax.reload();
        p.success('Medewerker is aangepast');
        $(".CountQ").html(""+data.msg+"");
                    $(".CountQP").html(""+data.msg2+"");
                    $(".CountM").html(""+data.msg3+"");
                    $(".CountMP").html(""+data.msg4+"");
                    $(".CountReal").html(""+data.msg5+"");
                    $(".CountRealP").html(""+data.msg6+""); 
                       } 
                      }
                
                });     
        },
        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
         if(xhr.status&&xhr.status==401){
       p.error('De Sessie is verbroken. Log opnieuw in en probeer opnieuw.'); 
        setTimeout(window.location.reload.bind(window.location), 4000);
}else{
alert("Er is iets onbekends misgegaan. Probeer later nogmaals."); 
               } }
    });
}
    } 
});
  });
});
```

I hope someone here can help me with this, I tried to put the name part on many places, but I think that it wont work because the employee I click is represented with the name atribute for the Id. But the row ID, client ID, will be the same no mather what user is picked. So How do I store that ID into a variable to post to my update php?

Comment: You should not be slapping `name` attributes on arbitrary elements like `span`, that is an attribute for _form fields_ (and anchors), none of which you actually have here. Use an additional custom data attribute. And it's easier if you put that on the `ul` to begin with. Then you just have to navigate from the clicked button to that parent element (https://api.jquery.com/parents/) and read the attribute value; if you leave it on the span, then you'd have to go up to the div parent first, and then find the span in there.

Comment: Thanks for your reaction.What do you mean with additional custom data attribute? Do you have example on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for putting me in the right direction. It is working when I changed the script like this. Just getting the datatable data value as id.

```
  $("#planningTable").on("click", ".ChangeEmployee", function () {
    var dataTable = $('#planningTable').DataTable();
    const rowData = dataTable.row($(this).closest('tr')).data();
    var ClientId = rowData.client_id;
    var EmployeeId = $(this).val();

    {data: 'resposible_client',
     render: function ( data, type, row, meta ) {
       return ' <div class="intplan_menudropdown dropdown" ><span>'+data+' </span><span aria-label="editdetails" id="dropdownMenu' + row.client_id + '" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false" class="badge bg-secondary" ><i class="fas fa-exchange-alt"></i></span><ul class="dropdown-menu" data-clientid="' + row.client_id + '" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu' + row.client_id + '" >' + ChangeEmployee + '</ul></div>';
     } 
  } ,
```